# Print type of a structure without creating its instance

Tags: go

In Go, I can print a type of a structure by `fmt.Printf("%T",Struct{})` however this creates a new structure and hence taking up a memory. So I may just print `fmt.Printf("main.Struct")`, but then suppose somebody refactors the name of the `Struct`, then the print statement does not get updated and the code breaks.

How could I print a type of a structure without creating its instance?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? i.e. what will printing the type without creating an instance help you do?

Comment: It is for error reporting `errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("expected structure of type %T, but provided a structure of type %T", Struct{}, object))`, so no script would break, but the information provided would be misleading. I kept the question general as in some cases refactoring could break the scripts too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will *always* use reflect to get the name of the type, period.

Internally `fmt.Printf("%T", x)` uses `reflect.TypeOf(x)` (source: http://golang.org/src/pkg/fmt/print.go#L721)

Use can use `fmt.Sprintf` but it still uses reflection + the added overhead of parsing the format string.

```
name := fmt.Sprintf("%T", (*S)(nil))[1:] //lose the *
// or
name := reflect.TypeOf((*S)(nil)).String()[1:]
```

Comment: Why not use `Elem()`?

Comment: @nemo `Elem()` can be used only with the `reflect` package. But since `%T` uses internally `reflect` package, it is probably not necessary to avoid using it directly.

Answer (score 3):

One of the solutions is to use the package `reflect`:

```
fmt.Printf("%v", reflect.TypeOf((*Struct)(nil)).Elem())
```

which does not create any instance of the structure. It will print `main.Struct`.

Comment: It there is a simpler solution not using the reflection, I will accept that one instead.

Comment: you will not come around reflection since you are dealing with a type you do not know. You can check them with type switches but in the end reflection is the way to go.